# Where are the GPU functions on OpenCV 3.0?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I understood that in OpenCV 3.0 the module GPU has been replaced by module CUDA, or better it has been split into several modules.

So `cv::gpu::GpuMat` has been replaced by `cv::cuda::GpuMat`, fine.

But what about the functions?

Where for example have the following moved to:

```
cv::gpu::GaussianBlurr ?
cv::gpu::Stream stream;
stream.enqueueConvert(...)
```

Apparently they are not under cuda module (eg. no `cv::cuda::GaussianBlurr`). Where can this functionality be found in OpenCV 3.0?

Comment: Unfortunatly i don't find GaussianBlur even including cudaoptflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All CUDA-accelerated filters (Blur, GaussianBlur, Sobel, etc.) are located in `cudafilters` module: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudafilters/include/opencv2/cudafilters.hpp

New API uses Algorthim-base approach:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> filter = cv::cuda::createGaussianFilter(src.type(), dst.type(), ksize, sigma);
filter->apply(src, dst);
```

The new approach helps to reduce memory allocations for internal buffers and reduce overhead from filter initialization stage.