# How to use cuda Gaussian Blur in opencv

Tags: opencv, cuda, opencv3.0

I'm fairly confused on how to use GaussianBlur using cuda in opencv3.1

I was reading about cuda::createGaussianFilter

http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d66/group__cudafilters.html#gaa4df286369114cfd4b144ae211f6a6c8&gsc.tab=0

However, I have no clue on how I would go about applying the created filter to a GpuMat I had already declared earlier. With the standard opencv bindings it's as simple as

GaussianBlur(src, dst, Size(5,5), 0,0);

However in my code that uses cuda I have the following

```
Mat foo = imread(pathofimg);
GpuMat bar(foo);
cuda::cvtColor(bar, bar, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cuda::createGaussianFilter(????);
```

I'm unsure on how to implement this :/ Would appreciate some help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26916773/5707220

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out just now and I found that it is much slower than the default cv::cvtColor... I'm not quite sure why this is the case or what I am doing wrong.